# Android. get "JSONObject[\"response\"] not found." when make request with retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, http-status-code-500

I get error when I try to make request with retrofit in my android application.
I get 500 Interval Server Error

> "title":"Internal Server
>   Error","status":500,"detail":"JSONObject[\"response\"] not
>   found.","path":"/api/profiles/help/45.13367991428822/33.5960291326046","message":"error.http.500"

Here is my code:

```
 IApiService service = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitAuthInstance().create(IApiService.class);
        Call<ArrayList<Profile>> call = service.sendHelp(v1, v2);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Profile>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<Profile>> call, Response<ArrayList<Profile>> response) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), String.valueOf(response.code()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<Profile>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
```

And my Interface:

```
 @GET(Urls.SEND_HELP)
    Call<ArrayList<Profile>> sendHelp(@Path("latitude") String latitude,
                                      @Path("longitude") String longitude);
```

Please, help me.

Comment: try to hit the same URL on the POSTMAN. And see what will happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously problem is with object serialization on server side. 
Status code 5xx stands for error that happened on server.
There is nothing you can do with your Retrofit client to fix it.